# How do I define multiple values to a variable and return its value to me when it's the same in all functions?

Tags: python

I'd like to see the values of t when the values of AlfaSegundo, AlfaMinuto and AlfaHora are the same.

```
def PosicaodoponteiroSegundo(t):
    AlfaSegundo = 6 * t % 360
    return AlfaSegundo

def PosicaodoponteiroMinuto(t):
    AlfaMinuto = t / 10 % 360
    return AlfaMinuto

def PosicaodoponteiroHora(t):
    AlfaHora = t / 120 % 360
    return AlfaHora


a = PosicaodoponteiroSegundo(t)
b = PosicaodoponteiroMinuto(t)
c = PosicaodoponteiroHora(t)

def Instantes(a, b, c):
    a = b
    b = c
    return t

print Instantes(a, b, c)
```

What should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `if a == b == c` ?

Comment: You appear to be asking what values of `t` make `6 * t % 360`, `t/10%360`, and `t/120%360` equal. Python doesn't have anything like that built-in.

Comment: Your question is very imprecise. Do you want to find the `t` which gives `a=b=c`, as chepner suggested or something else? Also, what have you tried? If you want to solve equations I use `numpy.linalg.solve` as a workhorse for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this does what you think it does

```
def Instantes(a, b, c):
    a = b
    b = c
    return t

print Instantes(a, b, c)
```

Within the function, `a`, `b`, and `c` all refer to the values that you passed in. Effectively you could replace `print Instantes(a, b, c)` with `print t`

All you have to do here is say:

```
if a == b == c:
    print t
```

---

**EDIT:**

Because you are using the mod, you can never reverse the function. What you can do instead is write a function that takes `t` and passes it to your other functions.

```
def some_function(t):
    segundo = PosicaodoponteiroSegundo(t)
    minuto = PosicaodoponteiroMinuto(t)
    hora = PosicaodoponteiroHora(t)
    if segundo == minuto == hora:
        print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still says t is not defined, and I don't know how to define t to multiple values, I want to know the 2100th value of t.

Comment: only because t is global ... but yeah I think he wants to reverse his earlier calculations ... still you are correct

Comment: @user2985320 if it says `NameError: t is not defined` then you have not given us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry, it says Line 18: NameError: name 't' is not defined . I want to define t so it can give me back the values of t.

Comment: I think the edit is the answer he needs(+1) ... I tried to explain reversing the calculation but so much data is irreversibly lost ...

Answer (score 0):

```
a = PosicaodoponteiroSegundo(t) = (6 * t) % 360
b = PosicaodoponteiroMinuto = (t / 10) % 360
c = PosicaodoponteiroHora = (t / 120) % 360
```

for now you can probably ignore the modulo's

```
a = 6*t
b = t/10
c = t/120
```

this leads to solve for t S.T.

```
t = a/6.0
t = b*10
t = c*120
```

unfortunately this does ignore the modulo 360 which is likely unrecoverable as well as the truncation of your division so `t=a/6.0` is likely your best bet